# notification method NotificationCompat - no errors - no notification

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to get a simple notification.  I've seen lots of examples using old API methods, but i want to use the newer method.  I have put this code together from the API resource, and it runs without error.  However, i am not seeing any notifications.  I have the minimum required to view a notification, at least, i believe so from what i have read.  Here is my code :

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    public static Context ctx;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ctx = this;
 }

private static void notice(String msgfrom, String msg) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("New message from " + msgfrom.toString());
    mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
    mBuilder.build();
}
}
```

THANKS TO HELP BELOW, I MODIFIED MY CODE TO THIS

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nb =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
nb.setContentTitle("New message from " + msgfrom.toString());
nb.setContentText(msg);
nb.setAutoCancel(true);

Notification notification = nb.build();
NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager)         
ctx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NM.notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you want to run Notification in All Android device <= android 4.2 then just add `android-support-v4.jar` file in you Project and

use below code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

**this code is work in android 2.1 to 4.2.**

for more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15739018/1168654) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15760297/1168654) links.

Comment: Most excellent.. Thank you...   I shorted down my code for my situation, but it was your code that got me there!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the last step. You are building your notification, and you still need to post it to the system, in the following manner :

```java
( (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService ( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE ) ).notify ( 100 , mBuilder.build () );
```

---

**EDIT :**

The integer 100 (that I chose randomly) used in the **notify** method is a unique identifier for the notification. You should use the same identifier if you ever need to update or cancel your notification.

---

**NOTE :**

You might have a memory leak by storing your activity's contact in a static variable !
Instead of that, you can change this :

```
private static void notice(String msgfrom, String msg)
```

to this

```
private static void notice(Context ctx , String msgfrom, String msg)
```

and hence delete the static variable.

Comment: Thanks, yea, i derived that from 'Dhaval Sodha Parmar' response.  It's a learning curve...

Comment: As for you suggestion to not storing my activity in a static variable.  Good suggestion -  I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Just call inside your `onCreate()`

```
    Public void Player_Notification()
    {
    final String myBlog = "http://android-er.blogspot.com/";
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Audio Track is playing in background!",System.currentTimeMillis());
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

     // here is title
    String notificationTitle = Title;
     // here is sub title
    String notificationText = data; 
    // write your activity name which you want to open when user click on notification
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Activty.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Activty.this, 0, myIntent,
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  // intent will call your activity as you want
   myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
   myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle,
   notificationText, pendingIntent);
   notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

    }
```

Comment: this isn't using the NotificationCompat